# SQL query built from c# method optional parameters

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have an app that I need to allow a user the ability to select a month / year / user and then do a SQL query with those results. The part that's stumping me is I want each parameter to be optional.

So if I select a user, but no date info, I want to see all of that user's results from all time. If I only select a month, I want to show current year of that month, etc. I had it working with month/user with this code:

```
    protected void btnView_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        gvbind(Convert.ToInt32(ddlMonth.SelectedValue), ddlWebmasters.SelectedValue.ToString(), Convert.ToInt32(ddlYear.SelectedValue));
    }

    protected void gvbind(int month = 0, string user = "")
    {
        string query = "Select * from WebLogs w inner join(select max(ID) as id, username from WebLogs group by Username) w2 on w.id = w2.id and w.Username = w2.username where Year(LogEntryDate) = year(getDate())";

        if (user.Length > 0 && month > 0)
        {
            query = "SELECT * FROM [WebLogs] WHERE ([Username] = '" + user + "') AND month(LogEntryDate) =" + month + " AND year(LogEntryDate) = year(getdate()) ORDER BY [ID]";
        }
        else if (user.Length > 0 && month == 0)
        {
            query = "SELECT * FROM [WebLogs] WHERE ([Username] = '" + user + "') AND year(LogEntryDate) = year(getdate()) ORDER BY [ID]";
        }
        else if (user.Length == 0 && month > 0)
        {
            query = "SELECT * FROM [WebLogs] WHERE month(LogEntryDate) =" + month + "AND year(LogEntryDate) = year(getdate())  ORDER BY [ID]";
        }
```

And that passes the query into a `SqlCommand`, but now that I've added year this just is really inefficient and I know there has to be a simple way to handle this.

Comment: Use parameters! Search for SQL Injection

Comment: Or use LINQ, where you can compose queries rather more easily...

Comment: You might take a look at this article which explains how to handle this type of catch all query so that is safe from sql injection and fast. http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/

Comment: where are you going to get the data from i.e. `txtbox.Text` as we will need to see that to write the new code?

Comment: Added the onclick that calls the function containing my sql query. It populates from drop downs.

Comment: Since you are using sql server you SHOULD create a stored procedure with optional parameters and handle this request server side, like this you can be hacked using sql injection.

Comment: Regardless of how you get those variables you should always use parameters, you never know who may be reusing these methods after you and they may assume you used parameters.

Comment: Even if you know where they come from it is pretty easy to spoof this stuff by creating a page with a form that has an action of your page. As long as my form objects have the same name I can supply whatever value I want.

Comment: The users have to get past authentication to get to this section of code, and the information contained is not sensitive in nature. So the sql injection threat here is almost nothing. All I'm looking for is a simple way to code the logic of grabbing these parameters from the front end and handle it properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
protected void gvbind(int month = 0, string user = "")
    {
        //string query = "Select * from WebLogs w inner join(select max(ID) as id, username from WebLogs group by Username) w2 on w.id = w2.id and w.Username = w2.username where Year(LogEntryDate) = year(getDate())";

        string query = string.Empty;
        query = "SELECT * FROM [WebLogs] WHERE "+((user.Length>0)?"([Username] = '" + user + "') AND ":"") +   ((month>0)?" month(LogEntryDate) =" + month+ "AND ":"") + " year(LogEntryDate) = year(getdate()) ORDER BY [ID]";

    }
```